# What kind of test cases are convenient to use for testing the code for Euler equations of gas dynamics in polar coordinates?

Tags: pde, matlab, fluid-dynamics, boundary-conditions, finite-volume

Consider Euler equation of gas dynamics in polar coordinates as
$$
\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
\rho \\
\rho u_{r}  \\
\rho u_{\theta} \\
E \end{array} \right)_{t} + 
\frac{1}{r} \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
r \rho u_{r} \\
r (\rho u_{r}u_{r} + p)\\
r \rho u_{r} u_{\theta}\\
r u_{r}(E + p)\end{array} \right)_{r} + 
\frac{1}{r} \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
\rho u_{\theta} \\
\rho u_{r}u_{\theta} \\
\rho u_{\theta} u_{\theta} + p\\
u_{\theta}(E + p)\end{array} \right)_{\theta} =  \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0 \\
\frac{p}{r} + \frac{\rho u_{\theta} u_{\theta}}{r} \\
-\frac{\rho u_{r} u_{\theta}}{r}\\
0\end{array} \right)
$$

- Velocity of shock waves are my interest for this problem.
- The finite volume numerical method is picked to obtain approximate solutions for this system.

Before I run my code for my problem ,which does not have an analytical solution so I can't be certain if my code is correct or not, is there any test cases that I can use to test my code ?

For my problem boundary conditions are quite challenging, what kind should I pick and how to apply it to my FVM scheme ?

Matlab is the preferable language for this calculation. 
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

As a starting point, "method of manufactured solutions" can be used to check the validity of your code. For information regarding this: http://www.innovative-cfd.com/manufactured-solutions.html, or you can just google about manufactured solutions.

Roughly, CFL condition scales as $h^2$ instead of $h$ if you use  artificial diffusion terms. For DG methods, it is typically given by:
$$
\Delta t \sim \frac{1}{\lambda_{max}\frac{N^2}{h} + ||\nu||_{L^\infty}\frac{N^4}{h^2}} 
$$
where N is the approximation polynomial degree. 
For reference:

- http://www.springer.com/mathematics/computational+science+%26+engineering/book/978-0-387-72065-4
- http://www.researchgate.net/publication/48208658_Viscous_Shock_Capturing_in_a_Time-Explicit_Discontinuous_Galerkin_Method

Boundary conditions question needs to be more concrete I think for the community to help.

Comment: MMS method is definitely useful to check convergence rate for the scheme. I used this method for the 2D Euler equations in cartesian coordinates and it works very well without including boundary conditions. For that case I used sinus and cosines functions which depend only on x and y independent variables. To test above problem, is it going to be the similar case? Could you give me some example?

Comment: It is going to be exactly like cartesian coordinates. The only difference is $x$ and $y$ are now $r$ and $\theta$. Take a smooth soution for your unknowns (in terms of $r$ and $\theta$), substitute them in the governing equations and add the extra terms that you get as source terms.